# How Do I Add a News Ticker to my html code

Tags: html, css, news-ticker

yet another question, I've been trying to find html or css code that adds a horizontal and moving news ticker, yet everything that I've found was not helpful. I would prefer anything but the marquee tag

Comment: If u don't want it like marquee then how u want it cause what u asking can be done with marquee ?

Comment: @VishalKamlapure He's asking for an alternative. He doesn't need to have tried anything. Please be careful about what you are saying before blurting things out.

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Comment: A news ticker is a UI element that displays a large amount of content, in a small amount of space, non-interactively. It's great for situations when you want to present information on a single display to a group of people, since they can't individually scroll it at the speed that suits them. It has costs though, the speed it scrolls at is not tailored to the user and when someone starts reading it they will have to wait for the start point to come around again. It's a **terrible** UI element on the WWW where one person controls the browser and can just use scrollbars.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.slideText {
display: block;
width: 500px;
height: 30px;
background: red;
color: #fff;
overflow: hidden;
}
.slidingtext {
padding: 5px;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 15s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}

@keyframes example {
  from {transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 500, 5)}
  to {transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -344, 5)}
}
```

```html
<div class="slideText">
<div class="slidingtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
</div>
```